# Захват сетевого трафика

Tags: linux, трафик, tcpdump

Сейчас реализовано с помощью tcpdump запись трафика на Linux (Centos 7).
Нужно записывать трафик в pcap файлы в реальном времени. Трафика много и tcpdump не справляется.
Нашел немного информации о pf_ring только нет конкретики
Может у кого то есть кейсы как это реализовать ?

Comment: какая глубина архива нужна?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начните с настройки n2disk, у него хорошая документация.

https://www.ntop.org/guides/n2disk/

потом или параллельно настраиваешь pf_ring https://www.ntop.org/guides/pf_ring/get_started/packages_installation.html и стартуем